# Implementing a stack class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement a stack class using linked list here is my stack.h

```
// File: Stack.h

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
class Stack
{

private:
    struct linklst{
        int num;
        int* next;
    };

    linklst* top;

public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();

    void push(int i);
    int pop();
    bool isempty();

};

#endif
```

and my stack .cpp

```
// Stack.cpp

#include"Stack.h"
using namespace std;

 Stack::Stack(){
     top = new linklst();
     top->num = -1;
     top->next = nullptr;

 };

 Stack::~Stack() {

     linklst * r = new linklst();
     while (true)
     {

         r = top;
         top = top->next;
         delete r;


     }

     delete top;


 };

 void Stack::push(int i){

     linklst * r = new linklst();
     r->num = i;
     r->next = top;
     top = r;


 };

int Stack::pop(){

    if (!isempty){
        linklst * r = top;
        top = top->next;
        int x = r->num;
        delete r;
        return x;

    }


};

bool Stack::isempty(){

    return (top->next == nullptr);

};
```

My problem is in the cpp file whenever I try to to assign top to r, like for example in the push function r->next = top;
 I get this error " a value of type stack::linllst * can't be assigned to an entity of type int * "

Does anyone know what is it that I am doing wrong ??

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `int* next;` be `linklst* next;`?  A node in a linked list should point to the next node, not the data the next node contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, your linked-list interface/data structure is slightly off regardless of the stack desires.

More precisely exactly what it says is the problem is the biggest problem: your class definition doesn't provide you with a way to insert a `linklist` into a `linklist` yet that is what you are doing, and quite correctly I might add.

In the line of code `top = top->next;` You are trying to assign `r`, a pointer to a `linklist *` to `next`, a pointer to an int.  As stated above the intention is correct, the definitions are wrong.  `next` should instead be a pointer to a `linklist`.

```
struct linklst {
    int num; // current payload 
    linklst* next; // pointer to the next linklst, NULL for EOL. (Not an int*)
};
```

*Updated*

For more information and for other problems in your code have a look at Vlad's answer

Comment: I defined top as a pointer to a linkedlist as you can see in the header file. I can't see where did I define it as an int pointer

Comment: yeah i had a typo, `top` should have said `next`

Answer (score 5):

Change structure definition from

```
struct linklst{
    int num;
    int* next;
};
```

to

```
struct linklst{
    int num;
    linklst* next;
};
```

Nevertheless even after this change your code will be wrong. For example there is a memory leak in the destructor

```
 Stack::~Stack() {

     linklst * r = new linklst();
     while (true)
     {

         r = top;
         top = top->next;
         delete r;


     }

     delete top;


 };
```

At first you allocate new linklst and assign it address to r but then in the loop you reassign r.
There are other errors in your design of the stack

For example there is no need to allocate a "dummy" top in the constructor. I would define the constructor the following way

```
Stack::Stack()
{
     top = NULL; // or nullptr
}
```

Amd member function isempty would look as

```
bool Stack::isempty()
{
    return ( top == nullptr);
}
```

Also member function pop has undefined behaviour because it returns nothing in case when the stack is empty

```
int Stack::pop(){

    if (!isempty){
        linklst * r = top;
        top = top->next;
        int x = r->num;
        delete r;
        return x;

    }

};
```

Comment: This has many other excellent points in addition to our common answer

Comment: @UpAndAdam I wrote CTRACE record filtering for the IBM NFS Server using object-oriented features of PL/X. It is the best code among the code of the NFS Server.:)